# Eclipse. How to activate tooltip popup using shortcut?

Tags: java, eclipse, popup, tooltip, keyboard-shortcuts

for example we have following method:

```
...

public void method1(){
    method2();
}
...
```

`method2` can throws exception and `Eclipse` offer either wrap by `try catch` or declare `throws` declaration.

Each time I need pick up the mouse and hover mouse cursor to this row.[image]

Is it possible select wrap or throws without using mouse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your cursor to the method and press `Ctrl+1`, then use your arrowkeys. This trick (ctrl+1) can help you speed up development for a lot of things, like automaticly assign statements to variables.

Answer (score 8):

I think that 'F2' is the right key to see the tooltip visible when hoovering mouse over an item in Eclipse editor. It may contain suggestions of fixing if there's a problem with the item being hoovered over. The functionality is called "Show Tooltip Description".
Mentioned in other answers shortcut Ctrl+1 shows a "Quick Fix" tooltip which is slightly a different trick than "Show Tooltip Description". I would say that both tooltip provide user with some common functionalities but both offer also their own options.

Comment: The F2 key to display "Show Tooltip Description" is the hotkey I needed. I'm grateful for the hotkey, as it can show me contextual quick suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use `Ctr+1`keyboard shortuct. In your case, it is called quick fix and it works errors and warnings. With the same shortcut you can use quick assists, they are used for local code manipulations. Read more [HERE](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-quickfix-assist.htm).

Regards

Answer (score 2):

**Press <kbd>F2</kbd> for focus,**

[image]

---

**Using  <kbd>Ctrl + 1</kbd>  for proposal table,**

[image]